# javascript error unexpected identifier in text with emoji code

Tags: javascript

The following line of js code is producing an unexpected identifier error, how might I correct this?

```
var bd_msg  = "<div>Have a great day!</div><div><br></div><div><span id="emoji_1f600"></span></div><div>From all of us.</div>";
```

Error reported is:
Unexpected identfier 'emoji_1f600'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.

Comment: You cannot wrap the same kinds of quotes

Comment: you need to escape the `"` inside the string, `\"`

Comment: both answers are correct.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bd_msg  = "<div>Have a great day!</div><div><br></div><div><span id='emoji_1f600'></span></div><div>From all of us.</div>";
```

the double quote in between broke the string

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions. OP cannot delete answered questions

Comment: Both answers are correct. Thank you both.